# Accessing Ubuntu from Windows 10 via RDP changes the display language

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, language

I have installed xrdp on my Laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 (Display language of the system: English). I've another Desktop PC running Windows 10 (Display language of the system: French).

When I access the laptop from the desktop PC via remote desktop, the **display language** (not, the input language) of Ubuntu changes to French (Messages, Programs menus, Settings, etc.). However, when I access the language settings, English is listed as the default language.

How can I keep the original display language in Ubuntu when I access it from Windows?